# Error Handle on UI thread when http request returns an error

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, rx-java2

I am using Fuel and Rxjava to make network calls. I have set my base URL to localhost, which at isn't serving anything. I want to be able to handle network errors so I can show some sort of error message on the UI to the user.

Here is an example of my GET request

```
   fun getRandom(take: Int, responseHandler: (result: WikiResult) -> Unit?) {
    Urls.getRandomURl(take)
            .httpGet()
            .timeout(timeout)
            .timeoutRead(readTimeout)
            .rx_object(WikipediaDataDeserializer())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ result ->
                val statusCode = result.component2()?.response?.statusCode

                when(statusCode) {
                    -1 -> e(statusCode.toString(), result.component2()?.cause.toString())
                    else -> {
                        val (data, _) = result
                        responseHandler.invoke(data as WikiResult)
                    }
                }

            }, {
                error -> e(error.cause.toString())
            })
}
```

And on my fragment I am calling the above function in a async task

```
private fun getRandomArticles() {
    refresher?.isRefreshing = true
            wikiManager?.getRandom(15, { wikiResult ->
                adapter.currentResults.clear()
                adapter.currentResults.addAll(wikiResult.query!!.pages)
                onUiThread {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    refresher?.isRefreshing = false
                }
            })


}

private fun reportException(e: Throwable) {
    refresher?.isRefreshing = false
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    builder.setMessage(e.message).setTitle("Error")
    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
```

So I get a network error `java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80`

I want to be able to get this on my fragment and display an error on the fragment. Not sure what the best approach is for this.

You can see the full project code on here 
https://github.com/limpep/android-kotlin-wikipedia 
under branch feature/rxjava

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It is not necessary to mix AsyncTask and RxJava. Your network call is already running on a background thread du to `.subsribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())`.

Comment: Thanks will fix my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say how to write good code for this in your structure because your code is not very clear in its separation and it is not necessary to use `AsyncTask` and `runOnUIThread` when you are already using `.subscribeOn()` and `.observeOn()` on your observable.

Maybe this would be a better basis for structure:

```
fun getRandom(take: Int): Single<WikiResult> {
   return Urls.getRandomURl(take)
            .httpGet()
            .timeout(timeout)
            .timeoutRead(readTimeout)
            .rx_object(WikipediaDataDeserializer())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map{ if(it.component2()!=null) throw it.component2() else it.component1() as WikiResult }

}


private fun getRandomArticles() {
    refresher?.isRefreshing = true

    getRandom().doOnCompleted{refresher?.isRefreshing = false}
               .subscribe(this::handleResponse,this::reportException)    
}

private fun handleResponse(wikiResult:WikiResult){
    adapter.currentResults.clear()
    adapter.currentResults.addAll(wikiResult.query!!.pages)
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()                
}
```

Comment: The error is actually on `-1 -> e(statusCode.toString(), result.component2()?.cause.toString())`

Comment: I see. I added a mapping to my code where if there is an exception it will throw it and if not it will return the response.

Comment: I've taken a look at your code , the returned method is Type mismatch.
`Required:
Observable<WikiResult>?
Found:
Single<Result<WikiResult, FuelError>!>`

Comment: Yeah I assumed a bit about the return types of the other functions, it was more meant as an pseudo codish example. I updated the above code, but it might still need some tweaking as I do not have all the classes to compile a working example with your classes etc.

Comment: Thanks dude. This has greatly helped me. I've had to do a bit of changes as there is no `doOnCompleted` but i've changed it to `doOnSuccess`. I am in the middle of changing the other methods and I will commit this code full access to the code is available on  https://github.com/limpep/android-kotlin-wikipedia under branch feature/rxjava much appreciated